# EditText in tabs can't be selected in ICS

Tags: android, tabs, android-edittext

My apps has form in which user can add information about their enterprise. I used TabHost component for four categories. In XML I have layout of four forms in my app (xml code is below). My Activity with tabs works on various devices with Android Gingerbread , but it's not working on devices with Android Ice Cream Sandwich. When I want choose for example EditText number 4 in tabAddress on Android 2.3.3 I can selected those field and I can to write something in them. When I want to do the same thing on Android 4.1.2 or 4.2 I can't choose that field, because that mechanism not working in this version of Android. In last tabs I can choose all of EditText both on Gingerbread and ICS. I think it's work like layers in ICS and my last tabs (Menu) cover other tabs. Below are my xml code and fragment of Java code. How I can to resolve that problem? I want to it's work in ICS like working on Andorid 4.3.3.

XML code:
`

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:tabStripEnabled="false" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

                <ScrollView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tabAddress"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:padding="10dp" >

                        ... other components (e.g. EditText)

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/etName"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                            android:ems="10" />

                        ... other components (e.g. EditText)

                    </LinearLayout>
                </ScrollView>

                <ScrollView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tabDetails"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:padding="10dp" >

                        ... other components (e.g. EditText)

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/etPhone"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                            android:ems="10" />

                        ... other components (e.g. EditText)

                    </LinearLayout>
                </ScrollView>

                <ScrollView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tabHours"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:padding="10dp" >

                        ... other components (e.g. EditText)

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/etMonday"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                            android:ems="10" />

                        ... other components (e.g. EditText)

                    </LinearLayout>
                </ScrollView>

                <ScrollView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tabMenu"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:padding="10dp" >

                        ... other components (e.g. EditText)

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/etProduct"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                            android:ems="10" />

                        ... other components (e.g. EditText)

                    </LinearLayout>
                </ScrollView>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>`
```

Java code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ...

    tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
    tabHost.setup();

    addTab("Adres", R.id.tabAddress, R.drawable.home);
    addTab("Szczegóły", R.id.tabDetails, R.drawable.details);
    addTab("Godz.", R.id.tabHours, R.drawable.clock);
    addTab("Menu", R.id.tabMenu, R.drawable.menu);

    setTabColor(tabHost);

    ...
    }

public void addTab(String tabSpecTag, int viewId, int drawableId){
    tabSpecs = tabHost.newTabSpec(tabSpecTag);
    tabSpecs.setIndicator(tabSpecTag, getResources().getDrawable(drawableId));
    tabSpecs.setContent(viewId);
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpecs);
}
```

Comment: I'm still new Android programming and I could be wrong, but I think TabHost was deprecated and you should be using Fragments instead. That being said, I have not worked with Fragments yet so I will have to pass that to someone else with more experience.

Comment: Dlaczego ScrollView nie sa w tych tabach(linearlayout) tylko na zewnątrz?

Comment: Ponieważ ScrollView może mieć tylko jeden węzeł podrzędny. Na Gingerbread działa, nie działa na ICS.